# Python3 + Curses: How to press "q" for ending program immediately?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ncurses, curses, python-curses

When I run the following sample code and press just "q", it'll ends properly,
but if I pressed any other characters "for instance many breaks and a lot of other characters" and then press "q" it'll not exit, how can I solve this?

```
import curses, time

def main(sc):
    sc.nodelay(1)

    while True:
        sc.addstr(1, 1, time.strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
        sc.refresh()

        if sc.getch() == ord('q'):
            break

        time.sleep(1)

if __name__=='__main__': curses.wrapper(main)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pressing other keys cause `time.sleep(1)` call, you should wait `n` seconds (`n` = number of other key strokes).

Removing `time.sleep` call will solve your problem.

```
def main(sc):
    sc.nodelay(1)

    while True:
        sc.addstr(1, 1, time.strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
        sc.refresh()

        if sc.getch() == ord('q'):
            break

        #time.sleep(1) <------
```

Alternative: call `time.sleep` conditionally (only when no key was pressed, `getch` returns `-1` if no key was pressed in non-blocking mode):

```
while True:
    sc.addstr(1, 1, time.strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
    sc.refresh()

    key = sc.getch()
    if key == ord('q'):
        break
    elif key < 0:
        time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Many thanks @falsetru for you prompt reply, but as I mentioned it's a sample code, my real code is a top-like app with timeout/refresh-time option, so I must use sleep inside the code to match the defined timeout.

Comment: @M.Adel, How about calling `time.sleep` conditionally? (only when no key was pressed: `sc.getch()` returns `-1`) http://pastebin.com/JZgi9ewb

Comment: @falsetru Excellent!! please paste it as answer to allow me to accept it, and many thanks guys for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The function [`window.timeout(delay)`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/curses.html#curses.window.timeout) is most likely what you are looking for. Once a timeout is set, `getch` will wait `delay` milliseconds before returning -1.

Although using `time.sleep(seconds)` will work, `timeout` is much cleaner and will give a smoother user experience due to `sleep` delaying the processing of user input by as much as `seconds`.