# How should I be going about exiting python script when user types 'q'?

Tags: python, curses, python-curses

I'm trying to add code to exit my curses python script correctly when the user types `q`. I can't merely do `CTRL+C` because then curses won't be de-initialized correctly.

I haven't found a good solution with getting user input that has a timeout so the program doesn't sit there until the user gives some input.

Is there a simple way with creating a second thread that just handles user input and can request the main thread to run a de-init function?

Comment: See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24308583/python3-curses-how-to-press-q-for-ending-program-immediately

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The suggested answer [Python3 + Curses: How to press “q” for ending program immediately?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24308583/python3-curses-how-to-press-q-for-ending-program-immediately) is a starting point, but (like the suggestion for using a separate thread) is not what is needed.

Here is an example, starting from the former:

```
import sys, curses, time

def main(sc):
    sc.nodelay(1)

    while True:
        try:
            sc.addstr(1, 1, time.strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
            sc.refresh()

            if sc.getch() == ord('q'):
                break

            time.sleep(1)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            curses.endwin()
            print "Bye"
            sys.exit()

if __name__=='__main__': curses.wrapper(main)
```

When you press `^C`, it sends a keyboard interrupt.  If you catch that, you can tell curses to cleanup (and restore the terminal modes).  After that, exit.

A separate thread will not work because it is unlikely that the underlying curses is thread-safe (and improbable that someone has gotten around to using the feature from Python).

Further reading:

- [Why does (fill in the blank) happen when I use two threads?](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.faq.html#multithread)